# pairs of prime numbers, abs(p_1 - p_2) = 2, list or array

Tags: php

I'm new to php and am currently working through some exercises.
Problems: Find all pairs of prime numbers with: abs(p_1 - p_2) = 2, like: (5,7), (7,9), ...

First of all I have written a script for prime numbers:

```
echo '<pre>';
function primzahlen($nummer){
    for($teiler = 2; $teiler*$teiler < $nummer; $teiler++){
        $a = $nummer % $teiler;
        if($a == 0){
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

$anfang = 1;
$ende = 2000;

for($teiler = $anfang; $teiler <= $ende; $teiler++){
    if(primzahlen($teiler) == TRUE){
        $primzahlen[] = $teiler;
    }
}

foreach($primzahlen as $k => $v){
    $paare[] = [$v, $primzahlen[$k+1] ?? 0];
}


foreach($paare as $k){
    $primzahlen_paare[] = abs($k[0] - $k[1]);
}

print_r($primzahlen_paare);
```

I sort the prime numbers from $primzahlen to pairs of prime numbers (tupel) ($paare) and check condition in $primzahlen_paare.
So I haven't a final idea for a suitable loop.

Comment: How will you know when you are done?

Comment: For example I will find all pairs between 1 and 2000 (or whatever).

Comment: What is your exact desired result from input?

Comment: Hint: If you look up how to efficiently enumerate prime numbers you will not only find what is on that label, but also a surprisingly succint solution to this specific problem, which your teacher is probably planning to spring on you after this assignment is due.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize your existing function:

```php
function primzahlen($nummer){
    for($teiler = 2; $teiler*$teiler < $nummer; $teiler++){
        $a = $nummer % $teiler;
        if($a == 0){
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

function all_prime_pairs_between($anfang, $ende) {
    $pairs = [];
    for ($n = $anfang; $n <= $ende; ++$n) {
        if (primzahlen($n) && primzahlen($n + 2)) {
            $pairs[] = [$n, $n + 2];
        }
    }
    return $pairs;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(all_prime_pairs_between(1, 2000));
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.